# The Spearman rank correlation coefficient (Excel)

Tags: excel, correlation, rank

I got 2 ranking lists:

```
 r1 r2
 11 5
3   3
5   11
1   1
10  10
7   7
6   6
2   8
8   2
4   4
9   9
```

How can I calculate the  Spearman rank correlation coefficient in Excel? The result should be 0.95 but when I tried =CORREL(M4:M14,N4:N14), it returned 0.345454545. Could anyone tell how to calculate in the right way ?

Comment: A [quick google](http://www.real-statistics.com/correlation/spearmans-rank-correlation/) suggests you should include the real numbers on the formula

Comment: Have tried it on this website http://www.wessa.net/rankcorr.wasp and get the same answer.

Comment: Pay attention, because the exact result should be r=0.34 (not 0.95).